# User field missing in system.profile collection when connecting with Mongos

Tags: mongodb, authentication, profiling

We have a MongoDB cluster and clients connecting to it through a Mongos instance. The individual mongo(s) in the cluster are all running with `--auth`, and the Mongo use a `--keyfile` when communicating with them. We are profiling slow queries but are not getting the user names on queries that go through Mongo.

To make it clearer:

1. If I connect directly to one of the Mongo, authenticate, and run a query, then I can look in the `system.profile` collection afterwards, and the `user` field will be populated with my username.
2. If I connect through mongos, authenticate, and run a query, then the system.profile collection contains profiling info about the query, but the user field is blank.

The authentication is required, I can't run a query through Mongo without authenticating first, but the user name just doesn't seem to be included in the profiling info, and we'd really like to be able to see it.

Any ideas? Any alterations I can make to our  configuration?

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: Hi, this looks like a bug and I have filed a ticket for you: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7538

Comment: @Ren Thanks. Then I know not to spend more time on it for now. I've looked at the ticket and upvoted it. We really need this to be able to easily figure out which apps are running slow or unindexed queries. If you change this to an answer I'll give you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to actually add an answer:

As Ren stated in his comment, he [filed a ticket](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7538), as this is related to a bug.